# Nativescript ActivityIndicator not listening properly to busy = variable

Tags: angular, nativescript

im creating a small app where I want to have an activityIndicator whenever a request was sent to a server.

So in my UI service I have a Subject and im listening to it in my ActivityIndicatorComponent. Result: It starts being "busy" but it does not stop even if the variable in the Indicator attribute "busy" is false.

So the Idndicator is somehow "not refreshed" after initialized once?

My UIService

```
    @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root'})
export class UiService {
    private _drawerState=  new BehaviorSubject<void>(null);
    isLoading = new Subject<boolean>();

    get drawerState() {
        return this._drawerState.asObservable();
    }

    toggleDrawer() {
        this._drawerState.next(null);
    }

    setIsLoading(value: boolean) {
        this.isLoading.next(value);
    }

}
```

My Socket Service who calls the Method in Ui Service:

```
export class SocketioService {
socket;

currentRoom: ChatRoom;
message_receiver = new Subject<Message>();
room_receiver = new Subject<ChatRoom>();


constructor(private router: RouterExtensions, private ui: UiService) {
    this.socket = SocketIO.connect("http://localhost:3000");
    console.log("SOCKET: " + this.socket);

    this.socket.on("chat room", (room) => this.onReceivingChatRoom(room));

}


onRequestRoomlist(data) {
    this.ui.setIsLoading(true);
    this.socket.emit("request rooms", data);
}

onReceivingChatRoom(room) {
    this.ui.setIsLoading(false);
    console.log("Received Chat Room");
    this.room_receiver.next(new ChatRoom(room.name, room.description, room.image, room.protection));
}
}
```

And finally im listening to the Subject in my ActivityIndicatorComponent:

```
export class ActivityIndicatorComponent implements OnInit {

  isLoading: boolean;

  constructor(private ui: UiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ui.isLoading.subscribe(
        (value: boolean) => {
          this.isLoading = value;
        }
    )
  }

}
```

Here is the xml to the ActivityIndicatorComponent

```
<ActivityIndicator #indicator row="1" col="1" width="50" height="50" busy="{{isLoading}}" color="#6495ed"></ActivityIndicator>
```

Comment: Can you share a Playground example where the issue can reproduced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket is probably running outside Angular zone, so when the variable is changed, it sends an update to your subject and, since it's outside the zone, doesn't trigger change detection.

This can be fixed in 2 ways:

1. As you already fixed, by manually calling `detectChanges()`
2. By running inside angular zone with `ngZone.run(() => {/* code */});`

You can also use this observable operator to ensure the code runs inside the zone.

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export function enterZone(zone: NgZone) {
  return <T>(source: Observable<T>) =>
    new Observable<T>(observer =>
      source.subscribe({
        next: (x) => zone.run(() => observer.next(x)),
        error: (err) => observer.error(err),
        complete: () => observer.complete()
    })
   );
}
```

So you can use: `this.ui.isLoading.pipe(enterZone(ngZone)).subscribe()`. Or even better, you can define in your Service:

`isLoading$ = this.isLoading.pipe(enterZone(ngZone))`

So you're sure whatever is subscribing to `isLoading$` is actually running inside the Angular zone.

Edit:

Example of the UIService with the observable:

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root'})
export class UiService {
    private _drawerState=  new BehaviorSubject<void>(null);
    isLoading = new Subject<boolean>();
    isLoading$ = this.isLoading.pipe(enterZone(this.ngZone));

    get drawerState() {
        return this._drawerState.asObservable();
    }

    constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}

    toggleDrawer() {
        this._drawerState.next(null);
    }

    setIsLoading(value: boolean) {
        this.isLoading.next(value);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! That looks awesome. Could you show me my UiService with your example code, so that this : `isLoading$ = this.isLoading.pipe(enterZone(ngZone))` works? I could not get it to work.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the example. All you have to do is subscribe to `isLoading$` instead of `isLoading` (you can even make `isLoading` private)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using a ChangeDetectorRef in the ActivityIndicatorComponent.

After receiving a a new value thorugh the subscription i called `changeRef.detectChanges();` and it works

Comment: You don't have to call change detector or zone within subscriber. Still the real problem may be something else you are missing with your service or so.